# How to read arbitrary object from arangodb using cursor.ReadDocument()

Tags: go, arangodb

I am trying to build a fairly generalizable service to create graphs in `arangodb`.

In my `ReadVertex()` function, I would like to be able to read a property with arbitrary fields of a vertex and read it into a variable, preferably a string without having to create a specific struct with the json tags hardcoded for particular properties.

I have no problem inserting arbitrary objects as a property of a vertex, and I've tried reading them into a string, but it always comes up blank.

An example of what I would like to accomplish: if a vertex has a property: `"Prop1": {"Nested1": true, "Nested2": false}`, and a property `"Prop2": "Just a string"`, in my `ReadVertex()` function I would like to be able to do something along the lines of

```
// query the database and get a cursor containing prop1 and prop2

var prop1 someType
cursor.ReadDocument(ctx, &prop1)
fmt.Println(prop1.String()) // should print {"Prop1": {"Nested1": true, "Nested2": false}}

var prop2 someType
cursor.ReadDocument(ctx, &prop2)
fmt.Println(prop2.String()) // should print {"Prop2": "Just a string"}
```

And I would like this to work having prop1 and prop2 be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the answer was a lot more simple than I thought it would be. This works if `prop1` and `prop2` are type `interface{}`, it reads the data in as a map, then as long as the keys in the map are all strings (which they are in my case), to turn it into a json string I can just use `json.Marshal()` and cast the returned byte array as a string.